# Is there any ruby gem/plugin to work with LDAP v3 on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ldap, openldap

I've spend some time trying to get information about users from my OenLDAP server. I have host OS Windows 7 and guest os Fedora 14 with OpenLDAP server installed and configured. On my guest os I installed `ruby-ldap` gem and managed to connect and search info however whenever I try to perform search in Windows (I have gem `net-ldap` installed) I get error `OpenStruct code=2, message="Protocol Error"` so I suppose it uses LDAP v2 and my server accepts only LDAP v3 So my question is -- is there any ruby gem/plugin to work with LDAP v3 on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to build `ruby-ldap` on Windows platform with ruby 1.9.2